# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{n+j}}{n!(j+n-1)^p}\frac{b_j}{j!}z^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation, double-sequence

I know that the following functional series is absolutely convergent for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $p‎‎>‎1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{n+j}}{n!(j+n-1)^p}\frac{b_j}{j!}z^n,\;(1)$$

where $b_j$ is the second Bernoulli numbers.

> My question is finding an exact value of the series (1)(or closed forms). Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

For example if the factor $(j+n-1)^p$ was not in the above series then by applying Bernoulli polynomial generator, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{n+j}}{n!}\frac{b_j}{j!}z^n =\frac{\pi e^\pi}{e^\pi-1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\pi z)^n}{n!}=\frac{\pi e^\pi}{e^\pi-1}(e^{\pi z}-1).$$

Comment: *Amount of the series ?* What does it mean ?

Comment: @  The Demonix _ Hermit, the series equel to what, I mean. (or closed form similar to my example).

Comment: Could you clarify what is $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{j} b_j}{j!}$ according to the definition of $b_j$ you are using, because what i find on the internet does not match your calculation.

Comment: @Rybin Dmitry, Certainly yes. Firstly as I said $bj=Bj(1)$ are the second Bernoulli numbers. Also the Bernoulli polynomials generator is $\frac{te^{tz}}{e^t-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(z)\frac{t^n}{n!}$.